# Qt library dependecy under Ubuntu

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

I have a Qt app with OpenMesh dependency. I built the OpenMesh library from source:

```
cmake ...
make
make install
```

It installed to the `/usr/local/lib/OpenMesh` folder:

```
libOpenMeshCored.a
libOpenMeshCored.so.3.2
libOpenMeshToolsd.so
libOpenMeshCored.so 
libOpenMeshToolsd.a   
libOpenMeshToolsd.so.3.2
```

The libs are included into the Qt project.

```
LIBS +=          -L/usr/local/lib/OpenMesh/ \
                 -lOpenMeshCored \
                 -lOpenMeshToolsd
```

When I start the application from Qt Creator, it works fine. But if I start the built executable from command line, it gives back the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libOpenMeshCored.so.3.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So why does it know about, where to find the shared objects, when I start it from Qt, and why not, when I start without it?

And how can I fix this problem?

Comment: When you say that you're starting it from Qt, do you mean Qt creator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cant use shared libraries in Qt project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071409/cant-use-shared-libraries-in-qt-project)

Comment: It would be helpful to know, what exactly happens when I start it from Qt Creator, in aspect of shared objects.

Comment: Did you run ldconfig after installing OpenMesh?

Comment: The ldconfig solved the problem, thanks.