# error while loading shared libraries - Qt pro file setting

Tags: c++, qt, kml, dynamic-library

By following this link,
[Cant use shared libraries in Qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071409/cant-use-shared-libraries-in-qt-project),
I add libkmlbase and libkmldom libraries in Qt project pro file

```
LIBS += -L"/usr/local/lib/" \
    -lkmlbase\
    -lkmldom\
```

those libraries are installed in /usr/local/lib
[image]

However, when executing, I have "error while loading shared libraries: libkmlbase.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
Even I copy the .so files to the executable folder.

Any suggestion? Thank you for precious time on my question.

Comment: try with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:new_path` where new_path is the path where you are .so

Comment: @eyllanesc: it works and thank you!!!

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to make it work through Qt .pro file.
Just curious if any alternative approach.
But sincerely appreciate your suggestion, @eyllanesc